# Double authentication connection cannot be redirected

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, authentication, totp

I am trying to set up a double authentication page under laravel, for that I add a checkTotp method that verifies that the user has activate double authentication and redirect this user to the page in question.

The problem is that I am not redirected and the code continues to execute.

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    ...
    $this->checkTotp($request);
    dd('after');
    ...
}

protected function checkTotp(Request $request) 
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();
    if (!is_null($user->totp_key)) {
        $request->session()->put('user_id', $user->id);
        return redirect('login/totp');
    }
}
```

What happens is that I enter the checkTotp method but the redirect does not work. My output is the dd('after'). I don't understand why I am not redirected. Can someone help me?

Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `checkTotp` function returns a redirect, but you want the `login` function to return that redirect, such that it is passed to the browser. You might want to move the redirect to the main function and let checkTOTP just return true/false.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    ...
    if ($this->checkTotp($request)) return redirect('login/totp');
    dd('after');
    ...
}

protected function checkTotp(Request $request) 
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();
    if (!is_null($user->totp_key)) {
        $request->session()->put('user_id', $user->id);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```